# Magento 1.6.2. add new Credit Card Types

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, credit-card

I am working on Magento 1.6.2. with custom build OptimalPayments/Netbanx payment Gateway. I need to provide an options for the customers to select VisaDebit and VisaElectron credit card types on the checkout page. Looking at the core code I see that Magento supports only Visa (VI), but not VD and VE. That means somehow I need to extend Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc class and js/prototype/varien/validation.js in order to add support for these card types. If anyone could advice me how to introduce these CC types would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visa Debit and Visa Electron are subsets of the 'Visa' card ranges. Highly likely then that you could just use Visa, no need to differentiate between Credit/Debit etc.